# Why an unbounded operator defined everywhere fails to be closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

The Toeplitz theorem says : If a closed operator is defined everywhere, then it is continuous.

So if a non continuous operator is defined everywhere, it is not closed. But why is it not closed? What condition fails for it to be closed? I thought if a (non continuous) operator $A$ is symmetric and defined on a dense domain in $H$, we can always close it (unambiguously) :

For $f$ where $Af$ is not defined : if $f_n \rightarrow f$ and $\lim Af_n$ exists (i.e. $A f_n \rightarrow f^*$), we define $\bar A f = f^*$  (It will be well defined because if $f_n\rightarrow f,g_n \rightarrow f,Af_n \rightarrow f^*, Ag_n \rightarrow g^*$  then $f^*=g^*$). For all other $f$, we define $\bar Af = Af$.

So $\bar A$ will then be a closed operator defined everywhere, and if it's non continuous that would contradict the theorem. Does that mean that $\bar A$ will be continuous?

Comment: You are leaving out completeness of the space, and that should not be omitted from this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

When you close a densely defined symmetric operator $A$, you get a closed operator $\bar{A}$, but $\bar{A}$ will (usually) still not be defined on all of $H$.  There will simply exist some $f\in H$ such that there exists *no* sequence $(f_n)$ in the domain of $A$ converging to $f$ such that $\lim Af_n$ exists, so your definition of $\bar{A}$ fails for $f$.  Indeed, Toeplitz's theorem says that if $A$ is unbounded, then some such $f$ *must* exist.

Comment: But what if we then set A¯f for that f (the one for which no lim A f_n exists) to some arbitrary value (say 0)? That should still leave A¯ closed (since no lim A f_n exists for any f_n->f, we can set A¯f to any value without affecting it being closed). Would it then fail to be symmetric?

Comment: Yes, that would break symmetry.  If $A$ is to remain symmetric, then $\bar{A}f$ needs to be defined so that $\langle \bar{A}f,g\rangle=\langle f,Ag\rangle$ whenever $g$ is in the domain of $A$.  Since the domain of $A$ is dense in $H$, this means there is at most one possible value of $\bar{A}f$ that will make $\bar{A}$ symmetric.  If that one possible value doesn't even exist (i.e., if the functional $g\mapsto\langle f,Ag\rangle$ is unbounded), then there is no way to define $\bar{A}f$.